# How to uninstall Cisco Packet Tracer 6.2

Tags: apt, uninstall, cisco

I downloaded the files from cisco (ubuntu installation files (with tutorial/student version)) and extracted the files. Yielding a folder `Packettracer62Student`. I ran the file install found in the folder. Agreed to the EULA, the script downloaded all the needed files. Basically everything´s working fine.

The problem is I want to uninstall `packettracer` and I can't find anything that works.

I already tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge packettracer`, and also `dpkg -r packettracer`. Both of which yielded that the package can´t be found. I tried to `grep` it in case it was named differently, still nothing.

What are my options in removing the software(package) of `packettracer62`?

Here is the `./install` script that I used from the package:
(I´m sorry about the formatting, I will edit this as soon as I figure out how to properly input the script)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Thanks to Felix Wolf (felix@bar.bz) for providing this install script.
# Thanks to Paul Fedele for providing script to check/download 32-bit library on a 64-bit machine
initInstall ()
{
echo
echo Welcome to Cisco Packet Tracer 6.2 Installation
echo
echo Read the following End User License Agreement \"EULA\" carefully. You must accept the terms of this EULA to install and use Cisco Packet Tracer.
echo "Press the Enter key to read the EULA."
echo
read cont
more eula.txt
echo "Do you accept the terms of the EULA? (Y)es/(N)o"
echo
read input  
case "$input" in
yes|YES|Yes|Y|y)
(installer);;
esac
exit 0
}

installer ()
{
SDIR=`dirname $_`
ARCHITECTURE=$(uname -m)
INSTALL_32BIT_LIBRARY=false

echo "You have accepted the terms to the EULA. Congratulations. Packet Tracer will now be installed."
read -p "Enter location to install Cisco Packet Tracer or press enter for default [/opt/pt]: " IDIR

if [ -z $IDIR ]; then
    IDIR="/opt/pt"
fi

if [ $ARCHITECTURE = "x86_64" ]; then   
    DEPENDS=$(dpkg -l | grep  yelp | tail -n 1 | cut -c1)
    if [ $DEPENDS = "i" ]; then
        TESTCONNECTION=`wget --tries=3 --timeout=15 www.cisco.com -O /tmp/testinternet &>/dev/null 2>&1`
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
            echo -"You are not connected to the Internet. Please check your Internet connection and try again."; exit 0
        else
            INSTALL_32BIT_LIBRARY=true
        fi
    fi
fi

if [ -e $IDIR ]; then
    read -p "It appears that Packet Tracer is already installed.  Do you wish to replace it? [Yn] " NEEDREPLACE
    if [ "$NEEDREPLACE" = "y" ] || [ "$NEEDREPLACE" = "Y" ] || [ -z $NEEDREPLACE ]; then
        sudo rm -rf $IDIR
    else
        echo "Program Terminated"; exit 0
    fi
fi

QIDIR=${IDIR//\//\\\\\/}

echo Installing into $IDIR

if mkdir $IDIR > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    if cp -r $SDIR/* $IDIR; then
        echo Copied all files successfully to $IDIR
    fi

    sh -c "sed s/III/$QIDIR/ $SDIR/tpl.packettracer > $IDIR/packettracer"
    chmod a+x $IDIR/packettracer
    sh -c "sed s/III/$QIDIR/ $SDIR/tpl.linguist > $IDIR/linguist"
    chmod a+x $IDIR/linguist


    if touch /usr/share/applications/pt6.desktop > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nExec=PacketTracer6\nIcon=pt6\nType=Application\nTerminal=false\nName=Packet Tracer 6.2" | tee /usr/share/applications/pt6.desktop > /dev/null
        rm -f /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt6.png
        gtk-update-icon-cache -f -q /usr/share/icons/hicolor
        sleep 10
        cp $SDIR/art/app_student.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt6.png
        gtk-update-icon-cache -f -q /usr/share/icons/hicolor
    fi

    if [ "$INSTALL_32BIT_LIBRARY" = true ]; then
        echo "Installing 32 bit libraries for Packet Tracer."
        dpkg --add-architecture i386
        apt-get -y install lib32z1
        apt-get -y install lib32ncurses5
        apt-get -y install lib32bz2-1.0
        apt-get -y install libgcc1:i386
        apt-get -y install libstdc++6:i386
        apt-get -y install libssl-dev:i386
        apt-get -y install libqtwebkit4:i386
        apt-get -y install libqt4-scripttools:i386
    fi
else
    echo
    echo Not able to create and copy files to $IDIR
    read -p "Should we try to gain root access with sudo? [Yn] " QSD
    if [ "$QSD" = "y" ] || [ "$QSD" = "Y" ] || [ -z $QSD ]; then
        if sudo mkdir $IDIR; then
            echo Installing into $IDIR
            if sudo cp -r $SDIR/* $IDIR; then
                echo Copied all files successfully to $IDIR
            else
                echo
                echo Not able to copy files to $IDIR
                echo Exiting installation
                exit
            fi
            sudo sh -c "sed s/III/$QIDIR/ $SDIR/tpl.packettracer > $IDIR/packettracer"
            sudo chmod a+x $IDIR/packettracer
            sudo sh -c "sed s/III/$QIDIR/ $SDIR/tpl.linguist > $IDIR/linguist"
            sudo chmod a+x $IDIR/linguist

            if sudo touch /usr/share/applications/pt6.desktop; then
                echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nExec=PacketTracer6\nIcon=pt6\nType=Application\nTerminal=false\nName=Packet Tracer 6.2" | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/pt6.desktop > /dev/null
                sudo rm -f /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt6.png
                sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f -q /usr/share/icons/hicolor
                sleep 10
                sudo cp $SDIR/art/app_student.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt6.png
                sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f -q /usr/share/icons/hicolor
            fi

            if [ "$INSTALL_32BIT_LIBRARY" = true ]; then
                echo "Installing 32 bit libraries for Packet Tracer."
                sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
                sudo apt-get -y install lib32z1
                sudo apt-get -y install lib32ncurses5
                sudo apt-get -y install lib32bz2-1.0
                sudo apt-get -y install libgcc1:i386
                sudo apt-get -y install libstdc++6:i386
                sudo apt-get -y install libssl-dev:i386
                sudo apt-get -y install libqtwebkit4:i386
                sudo apt-get -y install libqt4-scripttools:i386
            fi
        else
            echo
            echo Not able to gain root access with sudo
            echo Exiting installation
            exit
        fi
    else
        echo
        echo Exiting installation
        exit
    fi
fi



echo
echo 
read -p "Should we create a symbolic link \"packettracer\" in /usr/local/bin for easy Cisco Packet Tracer startup? [Yn] " QC
if [ "$QC" = "y" ] || [ "$QC" = "Y" ] || [ -z $QC ]; then
    if [ "$user" != "root" ]; then
        sudo ln -sf $IDIR/packettracer /usr/local/bin
    else 
        ln -sf $IDIR/packettracer /usr/local/bin
    fi
    echo "Type \"packettracer\" in a terminal to start Cisco Packet Tracer"
else
    echo "Type \"$IDIR/packettracer\" in a terminal to start Cisco Packet Tracer"
fi

# add the environment var PT5HOME
sudo sh set_ptenv.sh $IDIR

echo
echo Cisco Packet Tracer 6.2 installed successfully
}
initInstall
exit 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu) Especially [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926)

Comment: No, this question is about **un**installing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason apt-get or dpkg fail when removing this is that this application
isn't a ubuntu package at all.

It is a brutish script that does things manually and has no provision for easy uninstall (uninstalling it is easy if you aren't a newbie, still not a good reason to not provide an uninstall script, but anyway).

Let's see what it does.

It moves the main application and its files inside `/opt/pt`

generates a desktop menu item `/usr/share/applications/pt6.desktop` an icon `/usr/share/applications/pt6.desktop` and a symlink `/usr/local/bin/packettracker`

As you can see from the script itself, if you are not running a 32-bit system it is also installing manually a bunch of 32-bit dependencies. (taken directly from the script you posted)

```
sudo apt-get -y install lib32z1
sudo apt-get -y install lib32ncurses5
sudo apt-get -y install lib32bz2-1.0
sudo apt-get -y install libgcc1:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libstdc++6:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libssl-dev:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libqtwebkit4:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libqt4-scripttools:i386
```

So, if you want to nuke it and cannot do it from your file manager, remove the folder `/opt/pt`

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/pt
```

Remove the menu item and the icon, then refresh the icon cache

```
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt6.png
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/pt6.desktop
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f -q /usr/share/icons/hicolor
```

Remove the symlink in symlink `/usr/local/bin/packettracker`

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/packettracker
```

then, if you are in a 64-bit Ubuntu, you can remove the dependencies it installed (those I showed you in the excerpt above) with `apt-get` as normal.

SOURCE: I installed the same dumb thing on Debian Jessie, but it took some effort and I had to read that script on my own already.
I found this question while looking how to fix some of its dependencies as some of the packets it installs aren't there anymore in Jessie, or they have a different (thankfully multiarch-standards-compliant) name.